# retweet command of twint in colab

Tags: python, twitter, google-colaboratory

I have written the code below to scrape retweets:

```
!twint -u vrajabloo --since 2020-1-1 --retweets -o 20celebrity.txt
```

but when run it produces this error message:

```
Twitter does not return more data, scrape stops here.
```

I searched and also tried this too:

```
import twint

c = twint.Config()
c.Username = "vrajabloo"
c.Retweets = True
twint.run.Profile(c)
```

but this produces the same error message as above.

Why does this occur and how can I modify my code to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Profile method to retrieve tweets, for now, the `Profile_full` option is needed.  If the `Profile_full` option is not set to `True`, twint uses a URL that results in a 404, which is why you are getting no results.

See the code [here](https://github.com/twintproject/twint/blob/8cec66a256940d3daf9a9d34a5da8a61f26fe165/twint/get.py#L96)

```py
import twint

c = twint.Config()
c.Username = "vrajabloo"
c.Retweets = True
c.Profile_full = True  # <(==== You are forgetting this configuration option
twint.run.Profile(c)
```